# Need to Remove 'View Report Link' from dashboard in salesforce lightning

Tags: reporting, dashboard

I have a situation where I don't require 'view report link' in my dashboard view

Answer (score 1):

This is an limitation as of now according to this idea:- https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CUPFQA4

You can upvote for it. You can't hide it.